# POST не передает данные

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть форма регистрации и скрипт, который отправляет post'om данные на пхп скрипт, и тот должен записать все в БД после регистрации пользователя. Но проблема в том, что данные не передаются на пхп, и тот соответственно ничего в БД не пишет, в чем может быть проблема?
Вот форма регистрации и ajax скрипт:

```
<form action="" class="login__form">
   <div class="login__title">Sign up</div>
   <button class="login__button">
   <img src="img/login-facebook.svg" alt="facebook" />
   Login in with Facebook
   </button>
   <div class="login__reminder">
      By signing in via Facebook, I agree to the
      <a href="" target="_blank">Terms and Privacy Policy</a>.
   </div>
   <div class="login__divider">
      <span>or</span>
   </div>
   <div class="login__inputs">
      <input type="email" class="login__input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <div class="login__generate">
         <input type="text" class="login__input" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Username" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5,20}$" title="LOGIN can consist of 5 (five) to 20 (twenty) characters from: English characters (lower case), numbers and signs - (dot), (dash), (bottom_incident)" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <input type="password" class="login__input" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=.*[a-zа-я])(?=(.*[A-ZА-Я]))(?=(.*)).{6,20}" title="The password can consist of 6 (six) to 20 (twenty) characters, you must have at least one digit, one capital letter, one small letter">
      <input type="password" class="login__input" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password" required pattern="(?=(.*[0-9]))(?=.*[a-zа-я])(?=(.*[A-ZА-Я]))(?=(.*)).{6,20}" title="The password can consist of 6 (six) to 20 (twenty) characters, you must have at least one digit, one capital letter, one small letter">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdNG2UUAAAAAE0a5GdOhPp_CEzsj1niLSMCcxrb" data-callback="mySuperFunction"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="login__check">
      <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1">
      <label for="checkbox"></label>
      <span>I agree to the <a href="https://www.veraexchange.com/terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a></span>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="login__button login__button--blue" name="reg" id="registration"  value="Register" onclick="CheckForm();"> Sign up</button>
   <div class="login__links">
      <a href="">Already have an account? Log in</a>
   </div>
</form>
<script>
var capkeygoogle;

        function CheckForm(){
            var pass1 = document.forms[0].password.value;
            var pass2 = document.forms[0].password2.value;
            var login = document.forms[0].login.value;
            var email = document.forms[0].email.value;
            var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox');
            if (!(document.getElementById('login').checkValidity())){
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('Login is incorrect!');
                return false    
            }
            if (!(document.getElementById('email').checkValidity())){
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('E-mail is incorrect!');
                return false    
            }
            if (!(document.getElementById('password').checkValidity())){
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('Password №1 is incorrect!');
                return false    
            }
            if (!(document.getElementById('password2').checkValidity())){
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('Password №2 is incorrect!');
                return false    
            }
            if (pass1 != pass2) {
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('Password mismatch!');
                return false
            }
            if (checkbox1.checked == false){
                $('.alert').css('background','red');
                Alert_Opoveshenie('You did not agree to the terms!');
                return false                
            }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'send.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: {login:login, password:pass1, email:email, capkeygoogle:capkeygoogle},
      success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg == 'ok') {
          alert('Сообщение отправлено');

        } else {
          alert('Ошибка');
        }
      }
    });
        }

function mySuperFunction(captchaKey){
    capkeygoogle = captchaKey;
}
</script>
```

Вот пхп скрипт:

```
$password1 = "passwordlength16";
$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tm = time();
$password = openssl_encrypt($password,"AES-128-ECB",$password1);
$querylogin=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");

$numrowlogin = $querylogin->num_rows;

$queryemail=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE mail='".$email."'");

$numrowemail = $queryemail->num_rows;




if ($numrowlogin==0){
                if ($numrowemail==0){
                    require_once 'GoogleAuthenticator.php';
                    $ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();
                    $secret = $ga->createSecret();
                    if($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `user` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `status`, `last_act`, `reg_date`,`secret`) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '$email', 'false', $tm, $tm,'$secret')")){

                        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `wallets` (`user_id`,`contest_id`,`balbtc`,`balibtc`,`balusd`,`baliusd`,`baleth`,`balieth`,`balltc`,`baliltc`,`baleos`,`balieos`,`balbab`,`balibab`,`balxrp`,`balixrp`,`balbsv`,`balibsv`,`balust`,`baliust`,`baliot`,`baliiot`,`balbat`,`balibat`) VALUES (last_insert_id(),1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100000,0,100000)");



                        $valid_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE login='".$login."'");    
                        $valid_row = $valid_sql->fetch_assoc();
                        $id_act = $valid_row["id"];
                        $messageEmail = $mess." <a href=https://cryptocurrencytradingsimulator.com/activate.php?login=".$login."&id_act=".$id_act.">link</a> ".$mess1;

                    }

                }   

}
```

Comment: Поскольку вы отключили сериализацию данных `processData: false`, то вам надо или включить ее или сериализовать данные вручную.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko поставил true, но результата нет

Comment: Так вы форму НЕ аяксом отправляете, а по событию сабмит

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Comment: ну либо `type="submit"` заменить на `type="button"`

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk поменял тип, все равно данные не записываются

Comment: а аякс отправляется?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk ну в файле send.php у меня прописана отправка письма на почту юзеру, и письма на почту приходят

Comment: Вам нужно продебажить эти "спагетти". Поставить `var_dump($_POST['login'], numrowlogin)` открыть Панель инструментов браузера, отправить запрос и проанализировать ответ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk добавил var_dump($_POST['login'], numrowlogin), в консоли браузера показывает NULL
string(11) "numrowlogin"

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk что в таком случае делать?

Comment: вы попадаете `if ($numrowemail==0)` ?

Comment: var_dump($login, $email); есть данные?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk да, то что нужно

Comment: $tm, $tm нет кавычек

Comment: А вообще у нашего коллеги Ипатьева есть ответ как вставлять [переменные в запрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement).